# Catch share result in popup

Tags: javascript, facebook, popup, share

How to detect sharing result if I'm not using social network's Javascript SDK? All social network's stuff (authorization, sharing, etc.) happens in popups on my domain.

```
var popup = window.open('/api/share/' + service + '/page/123', '', 'top=' + top + ', left=' + left + ', width=400, height=500');
```

When sharing popup opens user can press Facebook's (or any other social service) share button and popup closes. But, user also can just close a popup without sharing. So, how do I know user shared or user closed a popup?

If I use social network's Javascript SDK, eg. Facebook Javascript SDK, it is pretty simple:

```
$('#shareButton').click(function() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
        caption: 'An example caption',
    }, function(response) {
        if (response === null) {
            console.log('user just closed a popup');
        } else {
            console.log('user really shared a post ' + response.post_id);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm using Facebook, Google+, Twitter and Vkontakte social networks on my web page and I really do not want to include four Javascript SDK on my web page (Twitter does not even have JS SDK actually).

Comment: may i ask why you want to know if the user shared something? btw, the feed dialog is deprecated afaik, you should use the share dialog instead.

Comment: I need share statistics displayed on my page — every success share increases total count of shares/reposts.

Comment: What is «feed dialog»? I'm using simple popup which redirects to Facebook URL and Facebook shows its own share form in this popup.

Comment: FB.ui with method "feed" is the feed dialog.

Comment: Oh, thank you. But I've mentioned FB.ui only for example — I'm not using Facebook JS SDK on my web page.

Comment: well, afaik you can´t get the post status with the redirect method, so my answer is most likely the best option - also the easiest one.

Answer (score 1):

It´s not really a direct answer, and i don´t work for that platform, but i suggest using something like this: http://www.sharedcount.com/

In one API call, you get likes/shares for all important platforms. It´s cached, so if you do the same call twice in a short time it will be very fast the second time.

The free plan includes 10.000 calls per day.

Comment: It only works with FB, G+ and TW, what if I use any other social networks?

Comment: then you have to add those manually - but sharedcount should cover all you need. i believe it even includes pinterest, for example.